# I want the sign up button to disappear when I sign up (in django templates)'

Tags: django

[image]

Model

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(TeamInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="member")

class TeamInfo(models.Model):
    leader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    team_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    member_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

View

```
class TeamInfoListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = TeamInfo
    paginate_by = 20
```

template (https://github.com/hyunsokstar/django_inflearn2/blob/master/todo/templates/todo/teaminfo_list.html)

```
{% for tm in p.teammember_set.all %}
    {% if tm.member.username == request.user.username %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button" data-id = {{p.id}} data-user={{request.user.id}} >탈퇴</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have two questions.

1.How can I make the sign up button disappear when a user is registered?
2.For logic seems to be inefficient at present~! Is there a way to improve it?

Thank you for letting me know about this.

=======================================================================

As you said, I created a logic using get_context_data and filter() in views.py so that solved the problem. Thank you

problem is sloved by this

```
class TeamInfoListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = TeamInfo
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(type(self), self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        myteam=TeamMember.objects.filter(member=self.request.user)

        if myteam.exists():
            myteam=TeamMember.objects.get(member=self.request.user).team
            print("myteam : ", myteam)

        context['myteam']= myteam

        return context
```

```
<td>
    {% if p.team_name == myteam.team_name %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button" data-id = {{p.id}} data-user={{request.user.id}} >탈퇴</a>
    {% else %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button" data-id = {{p.id}} data-user={{request.user.id}} >가입</a>
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: What rules you want to apply to <a> items? When do you want them displayed? The current template iteration won't work. More information regarding what you're going for there would help.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing a variable from your view?

**View Code**

```
def your_view(request):
    member_of_teams = TeamMember.objects.filter(member=request.user)
    context = {'member_of_teams':member_of_teams}
    return render("yourtemplate.html", request, context)
```

You can then use your for loop to loop through fewer elements.

As for how you hide the button, what you already have with the

`{% if tm.member.username == request.user.username %}`

should work. You just need to change it to see if the team matches with the elements in `member_of_teams`, not the username.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem with reference to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things here:

1. Override your get_context_data to return teams that the logged in user is a member of:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['logged_in_user_teams'] = TeamInfo.objects.filter(team_member__user=request.user)
    return context
```

Then simply check in your template if the team you're displaying is in that list:

```
{% for team in object_list %}
    {% if not team in logged_in_user_teams %}
        <a>Subscribe</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, note that we're iterating over `object_list` since that is what your `ListView` sets on context.

2. Keep things the same (but fix `object_list` in template) and write a small template filter:

```
{% for team in object_list %}
    {% if not team|contains:request.user %}
        <a>Subscribe</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Your template filter should look something like this:

```
def contains(team, user):
    return team.teammember_set.filter(member=user).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most optmized way is to use [**`annotation`**](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=django+annotate) like this:

First override the [**`get_queryset()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField

 class TeamInfoListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
     model = TeamInfo
     paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super(TeamInfoListView, self).get_queryset()
       queryset = queryset.annotate(subscribed = Case(
           When(teammember__member=self.request.user, then=Value(True)),     
           default=Value(False),
           output_field=BooleanField(),)
       )
       return queryset
```

Then in template:

```
{% for team in object_list %}
    {% if not team.subscribed %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button" data-id = {{p.id}} data-user={{request.user.id}} >가입</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way is most optimized because you are calculating if the user is subscribed or not in DB level, also it will be executed once.And you don't have to write any if-else logic in forloop inside the template.

Comment: Thank you
I solved the problem with reference to the answer

Comment: did you try the solution given with this answer :) ?

Comment: I think this is a better way but I'm a beginner;

I didn't apply it because I didn't understand

I'll try to tell you soon

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can set an empty else in django template to render nothing.

```
{% for tm in p.teammember_set.all %}
{% if tm.member.username == request.user.username %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button" data-id = 
{{p.id}} data-user={{request.user.id}} >탈퇴</a>
{% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm team_register_button">Subscribe</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I don't think it's a good idea for this situation. because If the user is not a member,  Subscribe button should be visible

Comment: I edited the answer. It is the simplest solution to your problem but if you prefer a more complex solution, I don't mind.

Comment: Thank you
I solved the problem with reference to the answer